# What changes need to be made to espresso machine so it can function properly in space?

Tags: espresso-machine

I recently read [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2847836/Female-Italian-astronaut-revealed-taken-specially-adapted-espresso-machine-International-Space-Station.html) about an Astronatur taking a "specially adapted espresso machine" with her to the space station and using it there to drink coffee.

Now this makes me wonder, what changes were made to the coffee machine so that it produced excellent coffee even in zero gravity?

All the article says is:

> Cristoforetti will be able to get her morning caffeine fix after celebrated Italian coffee makers Lavazza teamed up with space food specialist engineering firm Argotec to create a special and lightweight machine.

Which doesn't really give much technical information about the change itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to dig up this press release:
http://www.lavazza.com/en/.content/document/pdf/PR_Italian-espresso-in-orbit.pdf

> The first capsule-based espresso system able to work in the extreme
> conditions of space is here. It is called ISSpresso and is the
> brainchild of two Italian companies — Argotec and Lavazza — in
> collaboration with the Italian Space Agency
>
> Turin, 13 June 2014 – “An espresso coffee is what I miss most aboard
> the International Space Station.” We have repeatedly heard this
> comment from the Italian astronauts who for 13 years have been at
> times working in the International Space Station, and today their
> espresso wish is about to become reality. In fact, Argotec and Lavazza
> are working together with the Italian Space Agency (ISA) to actually
> bring the authentic Italian espresso onto the International Space
> Station. So in the Futura Mission — the second long-term mission of
> the Italian Space Agency aboard the Space Station — another Italian
> astronaut of the European Space Agency, Air Force Captain Samantha
> Cristoforetti, could not only be the first Italian woman to go into
> space, but also the first astronaut in history to drink an authentic
> Italian espresso in orbit.
>
> **Its name is ISSpresso.** It takes its name from the International Space
> Station (ISS), where it is to be installed. It is the first
> capsule-based espresso system able to work in the extreme conditions
> of space, where the principles that regulate the fluid dynamics of
> liquids and mixtures are very different from those typical on Earth.
> ISSpresso is the product of a project run by Argotec, the Italian
> engineering company specialised in the design of aerospace systems and
> European leader in the preparation of healthy and nutritious foods for
> in-space consumption, and Lavazza, the historic Italian coffee brand.
> ISSpresso is a veritable technological and engineering jewel, able to
> deliver a perfect espresso in weightless environment. This is why it
> was selected by the Italian Space Agency to be used aboard the ISS, in
> the framework of the Request for Expression of Interest that the
> Agency keeps constantly open to public-private partnership projects
> and activities to be carried out in the ISS.
>
> “Italian coffee is a beverage without borders — comments **Giuseppe Lavazza, Vice President
> of Lavazza** — and we have been thinking about taking the espresso into
> space for some time. Indeed, as far back as ten years ago we launched
> the espresso into orbit artistically with the photographs taken by
> Thierry Le Gouès and our Mission to Espresso calendar, which at the
> time may have looked like a work of science fiction but was actually
> just a vision of the future. In fact, today we are in a position to
> overcome the limits of weightlessness and enjoy a good espresso — the
> indisputable symbol of made in Italy products — on board the
> International Space Station. We are proud to have worked on this major
> project with Argotec, through the Lavazza Innovation Center, our
> division dedicated to research and product innovation: a scientific
> and engineering challenge which we hope will improve the living and
> nutrition quality of astronauts engaged on long missions.”
>
> “Our aerospace engineers — stated **David Avino, Managing Director of Argotec**
> — have designed a new-concept coffeemaker, which is safe for the
> astronauts and able to function in microgravity conditions, also
> thanks to Lavazza’s experience as a leader in capsule extraction 2
> systems. The functional project was already completed in June 2013:
> Argotec had been working on it for about one year. This is an ultra
> high-tech project which has led to innovative solutions, applicable
> with immediate returns on Earth as well. ISSpresso is a technological
> challenge that meets very stringent requirements, imposed by the
> Italian Space Agency, in terms of technical functionality and safety.
> In addition to the engineering aspect, Argotec is also taking care of
> the European astronauts’ training and nutrition. Food provides an
> important psychological support and being able to enjoy a good Italian
> espresso may be just the right way to finish off the menu designed
> especially for each astronaut, helping him or her to feel closer to
> home.”
>
> **Roberto Battiston, President of the Italian Space Agency added:**
> “ISSpresso is a perfect example of the way ISA's decision to make ISS
> national usage rights available to public-private partnership
> initiatives can result in a valorisation of public resources for
> technological, economic, and social objectives. The ISA will bring
> ISSpresso aboard the ISS, thanks to bilateral cooperation agreements
> with the NASA, as it shares with the project partners the objective of
> improving the quality of life of ISS astronauts, as well as the
> astronauts who will take part in future long interplanetary
> exploration missions. At the same time, we are also proud to
> contribute to the promotion of the image and spreading of the
> Made-in-Italy brand at international or better “space”, level.”
>
> **A coffee break in space.** A prototype of the space coffee machine is
> currently being tested at Argotec’s laboratories and all the necessary
> functional and safety checks. In a subsequent phase, Finmeccanica –
> Selex ES will participate in the assessment activities aimed at
> launching ISSpresso into orbit with the Futura Mission crew, one of
> whom is the Italian astronaut Samantha Cristoforetti. The ‘corner
> café’ on the ISS will be the hub for socialising on board the Station,
> a sort of social network in space, a venue for getting together,
> chatting and relaxing: an aspect that should not be ignored in
> missions that keep the astronauts away from home for many months in a
> very challenging environment. The innovative capsule system will also
> be able to prepare not only a regular espresso, but also a caffè lungo
> or hot beverages, such as tea, infusions and broth, so that food can
> also be rehydrated.
>
> **Extra-terrestrial technology.** Every tiniest detail
> of ISSpresso is designed to respond to a scientific and engineering
> challenge: in fact, the machine studies have enabled principles of
> physics and fluid dynamics to be tackled, such as the difficulty of
> handling liquids at high pressure and high temperature in a space
> environment. Just think that the plastic tube carrying the water
> inside a normal espresso machine has been replaced with a special
> steel tube **designed to withstand pressure of more than 400 bar.** The
> machine is so complex that it weighs **about 20 kilograms since there
> are back-ups of all the critical components for safety reasons in
> accordance with the specifications agreed upon with the Italian Space
> Agency.** ISSpresso represents a technologically high-value project
> which, besides increasing the variety of flavour in the astronauts’
> menu, will help improve our understanding of the principles of fluid
> dynamics and conditions in microgravity. Some of the solutions adopted
> have led to international patents, which will be useful both for
> future space missions and immediate terrestrial use...

**tl;dr**

It looks like its a heavy duty capsule system designed to withstand high pressure that not only makes coffee, but makes tea, broth, infusions and re-hydrates food.

---

[Just found images on The Guardian:](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/nov/24/space-station-coffee-maker-perfect-espresso)

[image]

And on http://walyou.com/lavazza-argotec-isspresso/

[image]

Comment: Impressive searching skill! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, first result on google for "lavazza espresso on space station" =p

Comment: @ShadowWizard It doesn't give a lot of technical detail, but there's a few little nuggets in there.

Comment: Yeah, surely better than nothing. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I found a couple of images as well.

Comment: For all the technology in there, I like the name the best: **ISSpresso**. Golly, that's clever. :)